# Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'opacity' property is read-only

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid, pseudo-element, getcomputedstyle

I am trying to set the property value of my pseudo element css class via javascript file.

The problem is that I am getting the error shown in the title.

Is there any other way to set it?

Code in css:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, white 10px);
  }
}
```

Code in typescript file:

```
  protected onScroll() {
    const scrollList = document.getElementById('list');
    const list: CSSStyleDeclaration = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.list'), ':before');
    if (list.scrollWidth - list.scrollLeft === list.offsetWidth) {
      list.setProperty('opacity', '0');
    } else {
      console.log("not set");
    }
  }
```

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava no

Comment: @KathrineHanson Yes, it does, please read Wes Ruvalcaba's answer very carefully.

Comment: @Teemu thanks. this should be accepted as correct.

Comment: Well, at the time the question was asked, CSS variables didn't exist. Changing the class or some other CSS selectable attribute was the only reasonable way in 2010 (and still is, if you have to support older browsers). Notice, that Wes has answered the question 8 years later.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't allowed to write to the styles returned by `getComputedStyle` if they were computed by the browser (ie not set by JavaScript already or by a CSS file).

Instead of `list.setProperty('opacity', '0')`, use `scrollList.style.opacity = "0"` or add an `opacity` rule to the `.list` selector in your CSS.

Comment: hi. the first solution will not work because it will hide completely the list. I just want to hide the :before pseudo element or add to it the opacity to null. How to do it?